# Software or web to track changes on technical documents?

Tags: collaboration, requirements-management

I'm looking for a software that helps us keep track of our technical documents (specifically, requirements documents). We are in contact with the client, and he actively involves in the creation of these documents, but sometimes we're not warned of these changes and they're lost. We currently use Google Drive, but it's pretty common that he'd forget to mark his changes as "Suggestions", so that we can approve them. To sum up, is there a software (or website) that does:

- Keep track of lists, especially who wrote each item, who edited each item and at what time?
- Let the user reorder items in the list, being it a trackable change?
- Let you define dependencies between items in the list?
- Group items in groups (features, milestones, however you want to call it)?
- Enforce that a change needs to be approved?
- Allow the user to define roles, so that not everyone can change them and not everyone can approve them?